# How to assign to pixels in an image in eager tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a need to rasterize points into image form inside my model, and I can't figure out the right way to do this. The issues are 1) tensorflow doesn't handle "assignment" to tensors very intuitively and 2) eager mode doesn't handle creation of tensors very intuitively

Here's what I'm trying to do

```
rope_images = tfe.Variable(
            initial_value=lambda: tf.zeros([batch_size, self.sdf_shape[0], self.sdf_shape[1], self.n_points]),
            name='rope_images',
            trainable=False)
row_y_indeces = tf.cast(points[:, :, 1] / resolution[:, 0:1] + origin[:, 0:1], tf.int64)
col_x_indeces = tf.cast(points[:, :, 0] / resolution[:, 1:2] + origin[:, 1:2], tf.int64)
batch_indeces = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.reshape(tf.range(batch_size), [-1, 1]), [1, self.n_points]), [-1])
row_indeces = tf.squeeze(row_y_indeces)
col_indeces = tf.squeeze(col_x_indeces)
point_channel_indeces = tf.tile(tf.range(self.n_points, dtype=tf.int64), [batch_size])
indeces = tf.transpose(tf.stack([batch_indeces, row_indeces, col_indeces, point_channel_indeces]))
on_pixels = tf.gather_nd(rope_images, indeces)
tf.assign(on_pixels, 1)
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'
```

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to turn your Tensor into a ResourceVariable using `tf.Variable` (you will possibly want to specify that `trainable=False`), which supports assignement.

If you want to replace some values within a Tensor, you can also use `tf.where`, *e.g.* if you want to replace the `indeces` values of `rope_images` with `1`: `rope_images = tf.where(indeces, 1, rope_images)`, which effectively creates a new Tensor with either the retained initial values or the substitution ones. Note that you can replace `1` with a full-shape Tensor of substitute values, in contexts when you need more flexibility.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: using tf.contrib.eager.Variable and these suggestions helped